# Errno 13 Permission denied after a 2nd deployment to beanstalk environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to figure out why I am getting `Error occurred during build: [Errno 13] Permission denied: C:\\service\\GeorgiService.dll\` after I attempt a second deployment of my app with unchanged code.

I have a simple Asp.Net.Core 3.1 app with a couple of config files in the `.ebextentions` folder:

01-create-folder.config:

```
commands:
  create-dir:
    command: mkdir C:/service
    ignoreErrors: true
```

02-winservice.config

```
Resources:
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
        S3Auth:
          type: "s3"
          buckets: ["temp-poc-bucket"]
          roleName: "temp_poc_test_role"

sources:
  "C:/service/": https://temp-poc-bucket.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/GeorgiService.zip
commands:
  create-service:
    command: sc.exe create georgiservice binpath= "C:\service\GeorgiService.exe"
    ignoreErrors: true
    waitAfterCompletion: 0
  start-srvice:
    command: sc.exe start georgiservice
    waitAfterCompletion: 0
    ignoreErrors: true
```

The above config files create the `service` folder and then download a windows service from an S3 bucket and extract it in the service location (using the `sources` key).
When I deploy the app_bundle (i.e. my app + .ebextentions folder) to beanstalk everything works fine. However, when I attempt a second deployment (i.e. deploy the same bundle but with different version) the deployment fails:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause of the Permission denied error. It was due to the fact that the windows service (i.e. GeorgiService) was still running. Therefore creating a lock over the `ddl` file. What I did to solve the problem is adding a 3rd `.config` file that gets executied before the `winservice.config` file (i.e. I renamed it to 03-winservice.config)

02-stop-and-delete-service.config

```
commands:
  stop-service:
    command: sc.exe stop georgiservice
    ignoreErrors: true
  delete-service:
    command: sc.exe delete georgiservice
    ignoreErrors: true
```

end config order:

[image]